# Vagrant: PHP7.0-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: nginx, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, php-7, ubuntu-server

I have a new ubuntu/xenial64 box based Vagrant installation. Unfortunately the PHP7.0 service does not running

If I running the following `systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service` command this will be the result:

```
ubuntu@Project-Yii-Shop:~$ systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service
* php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-01-29 14:37:05 UTC; 16min ago
  Process: 2213 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, s
  Process: 2203 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/php/php7.0-fpm-checkconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2213 (code=exited, status=78)

Jan 29 14:37:04 Project-Yii-Shop systemd[1]: Stopped The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
Jan 29 14:37:04 Project-Yii-Shop systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
Jan 29 14:37:05 Project-Yii-Shop php-fpm7.0[2213]: [29-Jan-2017 14:37:05] ERROR: [pool www] cannot get uid for user 'va
Jan 29 14:37:05 Project-Yii-Shop php-fpm7.0[2213]: [29-Jan-2017 14:37:05] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jan 29 14:37:05 Project-Yii-Shop systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jan 29 14:37:05 Project-Yii-Shop systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
Jan 29 14:37:05 Project-Yii-Shop systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 29 14:37:05 Project-Yii-Shop systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The main problem that I tried to enable this service but the Vagrant Ubuntu ask for password and well, this Ubuntu in the Vagrant does not have any password. I googled on this problem but I saw this solution only and the above one.

```
ubuntu@Project-Yii-Shop:~$ systemctl enable php-fpm.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to execute operation: Access denied
```

So I do not know what I should do, because if I install PHP7.0 on a real Ubuntu server (not in Vagrant) I do not get this error.

I use NGINX server with the following config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       try_files $uri =404;
   }
```

I use this command in the Vagrant file to install PHP7.0

```
apt-get install -y git nginx php7.0-curl php7.0-cli php7.0-intl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-gd php-imagick php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql php7.0-pgsql php7.0-xml php7.0-zip
```

And this command run after the Vagrant is up in order to run php7.0 srevice.

```
service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Does anybody see any mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your php-fpm pool definition (`www.conf` ?) which is to be found in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d`. Seems you're trying to start the php-fpm process as user "vagrant" - a user that doesn't seem to exist in the box.

Usually the user `www-data` is used to run php-fpm:

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

Comment: Aha, you right. I checked another config file, not this www.conf.
Should I remove this line `sed -i 's/user = www-data/user = vagrant/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` from the Vagrant? Because this set the user.

Comment: I don't know vagrant at all, but from a OS/php-fpm perspective, php-fpm must be run with a user that exists on the OS. So, either add that user or run php-fpm as www-data.